# New project frontend tech

Tags: web, vue.js, frontend, elm

Our team is about to choose a new frontend tech.
The two finalists are Vue.js and Elm.

Can you please explain the reasons for why choosing each one, so we can take a decision?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look to this link for the detailed explanation for both techs and let me know for any further clarification https://www.slant.co/versus/380/11378/~elm_vs_vue-js

Comment: @SantoshSingh the linked article is very misleading, seems an automated text and compares incomparable metrics (like the first and most values). I don't know the answer, and this is also rather subjective. I guess you have to do your own research, try both and decide. I love vue.js which is simple, powerful and fast, but Elm seems really nice too. The downside of Elm is that I think it will be hard to find and onboard new developers.

Comment: read this book, it's short and worth your time before making a decision (http://www.oreilly.com/web-platform/free/files/why-elm.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Comparing the two technologies [here](http://www.stefankrause.net/js-frameworks-benchmark7/table.html) there performance is highly comparable, with Elm having a bit of an edge on startup time, and partial updates. Both technologies have an incremental adoption model, meaning that integrated Vue and or Elm into existing code bases is straight forward. Both utilize a virtual dom, ensuring your html never becomes out of sync with your javascript. Lastly, as far as hirability, where neither library is as popular as Angular or React, both have a high (developer wants to use the technology) vs low (jobs hiring for this technology).

Some pros and cons of each,

### Vue.js Pros

- Low learning curve
- Easily re-usable code base
- Familiar approach

### Elm Pros

- Solid protection against bugs (the compiler catches 99% of bugs)
- Enforced semantic versioning. (Downloaded an Elm package? The author cannot make breaking changes without bumping up the major version number.
- A single syntax for the view and the logic. (no special logic for conditionals, aka having a v-if in your html)

The short version is, you are set to win with either technology. If you had to pick between them, you can count on both of them to be very fast and easy to integrate and test. Pick Vue if you want a lower learning curve, pick Elm if you want less bugs.

Best of luck!

Comment: Good answer, but this is misleading: _"Both utilize a virtual dom, ensuring your html never becomes out of sync with your javascript"_. 
Virtual DOM does not protect the DOM from changes made from other code, it is instead a method for efficiently updating the DOM.